# PhpStorm terminal color bug

Tags: terminal, phpstorm, ansi-escape

I have upgraded my php storm to 2018.2.5 x64 and after that my terminal is showing strange characters:
[image]

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a regression: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-201957. Will be fixed in 2018.3 IDE version.